# AbortFormatting exception while modifing the ast node

Tags: eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

In short, while I tried to modify AST, the eclipse cdt gives me org.eclipse.cdt.internal.formatter.AbortFormatting, Code sample:

```
for ( IASTNode node : nodes) {
     rewriter.replace(node, node.copy(), null); 
}
Change change = rewriter.rewriteAST();
change = change.perform(new NullProgressMonitor());
```

this simple code just replace a node with a same copy of it, just for sake of testing, some nodes replaced successuflly and other gives me this exception

```
org.eclipse.cdt.internal.formatter.AbortFormatting: [1783/54] Unexpected token type, expecting:23, actual:Token type=1  image =IdleTime offset=89705
```

I have been struggling for a while to know the reason and how to solve it but with no luck

Comment: There are a number of open formatter bugs which trigger an `AbortFormatting` exception, such as [this one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=406231). What is the code you are operating on? What version of Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen - Version: 2018-09 (4.9)
CDT 9.5.4

Are you asking for code snippet?

Comment: Yes, the C++ code that this loop is operating on.

Comment: (Note: Eclipse 2018-09 is not "Oxygen". Oxygen was the codename for releases from 2017-06 through 2018-03. Photon was the codename for the 2018-06 release. Since 2018-09, codenames have been dropped and the releases are named just based on year and month.)